# How to not get notification from specific github action failing

Tags: github, notifications, github-actions

I currently have a github action running on PRs, which is supposed to fail until the user adds certain labels. I then get a notification stating that the action/workflow has failed.

I still want to get notifications from when the other actions in the project fails, just not this one as it is meant to fail.

How can I achieve this? is it possible?

As far as I know I can only stop watching the entire repository, or disable notifications on workflow fails for all repositories. I cant seem to figure this one particular use-case out.